# How to retrieve dateTime with milliseconds from Excel 2010 with XLConnect

Tags: r, excel, xlconnect

Hello I have been given an XL spreadsheet (...not my fault please keep reading...).

As you may know XL does not deal with datetime and milliseconds very well. For milliseconds to be DISPLAYED in a cell you have to select a special format `aaaa-mm-jj hh:mm:ss.000`

I need to load this XL sheet into `R` with `XLConnect` (I can't use another package).

[image: snapshot]

As you can see:

- What is in the FORMULA of cell `B2` is `2012-10-01 12:15:15`
- What is DISPLAYED in the `B2` cell because of my format is `2012-10-01 12:15:15.447`
- FYI I indicated the underlying numeric value of the `B2` cell in `B3`

My problem is that what I do

```
wb = loadWorkbook(currentFile)
dataFile <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet=c('Sheet1'),header=TRUE);
#or even when I specify the type (my real file is a 3 columns matrix)
dataFile <- readWorksheet(wb, sheet=c('Sheet1'),header=TRUE, 
                              colTypes = c(XLC$DATA_TYPE.NUMERIC,XLC$DATA_TYPE.DATETIME,XLC$DATA_TYPE.NUMERIC), 
                              dateTimeFormat='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS');
```

What I am getting is a `data.frame` with `2012-10-01 12:15:15` WITHOUT MY PRECIOUS MILLISECONDS

My question is then:

What can I do to make sure `R` loads this `datetime` with milliseconds (at once without me messing around loading a `numeric` and converting myself afterwards)

Comment: I do see this in the help file `?readWorksheet` "dateTimeFormat 
Date/time format used when doing date/time conversions. Defaults to
getOption("XLConnect.dateTimeFormat"). This should be a POSIX format specifier according to strptime although not all specifications have been implemented yet - the most important ones however are available."  so it's possible you're SOL until the next upgrade.  More investigation is warranted :-)

Comment: Since I clearly have nothing else to do :-), here's a possible workaround. If you can modify the Excel source, add a column with the formula `=A1-floor(A1,1)` to extract the numeric portion equal to the seconds... or heck, just reformat the dates as their numeric value and convert back inside `R` .

Comment: Hey mate, yes there is plenty of tricks I can do, pb is that in real life I have 100s of these files, I succeeded in formatting the file correctly from within R, believe it or not SAS can import those files correctly.... (SHAME) so I'll load those newly formatted files in SAS and export back to csv, or if I feel lonely I'll code some VBA to copy paste special value to strings the correct format... Lot of work for something simple, but I still have hope this package looks nice ...

Comment: Yup,  or write a macro to save all sheets as `csv`, use `read.csv` and some magic to convert the date-time strings into actual dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've logged and fixed issue [13](https://github.com/miraisolutions/xlconnect/issues/13) on our github repository at https://github.com/miraisolutions/xlconnect. Milliseconds should now come across. Just make sure you also set `options(digits.secs = 3)` before printing as otherwise milliseconds won't be displayed.