# How to retrieve milliseconds from Excel with XLConnect

Tags: r, import-from-excel

I have a followup question to the following question:
[How to retrieve dateTime with milliseconds from Excel 2010 with XLConnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718953/how-to-retrieve-datetime-with-milliseconds-from-excel-2010-with-xlconnect)

I have installed XLConnect 0.2-6 (which should contain the fix mentioned in the above-mentioned thread).

Now I try to do the following:

```
library("XLConnect")
options(digits.secs = 3)
a <- readWorksheetFromFile(
"C:\\Folder\File.xlsx",sheet=1,header=FALSE,startRow=3,drop=3,
dateTimeFormat='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS')
```

Unfortunately, I still do not see the milliseconds. I guess that I have to do something in addition, but I have no idea what it is. Can anybody help?